# converting a string to int in kotlin There is a problem

Tags: android, kotlin, types

why result is mines?
my problem is converting a string to int in kotlin .

```
class Test{
    val x="200000000"
    val y="11"
}


fun main(){
    val test=Test()
    println(test.x.toInt())
    println(test.y.toInt())
    val z=(Integer.parseInt(test.x))*(Integer.parseInt(test.y))
//or :val z=(test.x.toInt())*(test.y.toInt())
    println(z)

}
```

result :

200000000

11

-2094967296

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're witnessing an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

`Int` in Kotlin (like in Java) represents 32-bit signed integers, so their maximum value is 2,147,483,647.

What you're trying to do is multiply 200,000,000 by 11, which would yield 2,200,000,000 - more than the maximum value. So only the least significant bits of that number can be stored in the 32-bit of the integer, and you end up somewhere in the negative numbers.

If you want to reach this kind of values, you should either use `UInt` (unsigned integers, which can go twice higher), `Long` (which are 64-bit and thus can reach much much higher), or other more complex types like `BigInteger`.

Here is an example with `Long`:

```kotlin
val x = "200000000"
val y = "11"
val z = x.toLong() * y.toLong()
println(z) // 2200000000
```

Comment: Excellent answer!